# Unrecognized FAT32 USB?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm trying to access files from a 32GB USB stick on my Xbox 360S. I have another exactly like it that works fine. I've formatted the non-working stick a few times as FAT32 with different alloc sizes. When I plug it in it blinks, then stops, then I guess it tries again and fails.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening? I've tried to google for an answer but all I end up with is "format as FAT32!"

Comment: The XBOX360 uses a very simple process.  It creates 8 2GB files on the storage device.  It then fills those archive like files as they reach their 2GB limit.  Without knowlege of the flash device we cannot help you.

Comment: You should carry this question to SuperUser, you would probbaly get better results.

Answer (score 1):

If your flash drive needs to load drivers, then it won't work. When you put the flash drive in on a computer, it loads drivers, but the XBox360 does not do that.

Also, the XBox360 can apparently only utilize 16GB of the flash drive's space, so if you have a smaller flash drive, you might want to try using that instead.

Try following these guidelines and see if they help:

http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive

If that doesn't work, then there is really no way to fix the problem. You're basically at the mercy of whatever the XBox360 will take. Some of my flash drives had this same problem being put into other computers - it wouldn't recognize them, even after installing the drivers.

Sources: http://forums.techarena.in/video-games/1207100.htm